# Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS with persistentStoreCoordinator

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

From time to time my app crashes before it is fully loaded right at the following line:

```
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
```

The complete method where this if state is located looks as follows (I think this is pretty standard):

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

**Update**

The crash happens on the second time the `-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator` method is called. **EDIT**
The frist time it is called from the first viewController that is visible:

```
- (void)updateStats {
    NSLog(@"Updating stats");
    dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("updateNumberOfSchedules", NULL);
    dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{
         AppDelegate *theDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    ...
    });
}
```

The second time (when the crash sometimes occurs when my DeviceLinker class is going to check the database for inactive links in my checkInactiveLinks method. This method is called upon launch in `applicationDidBecomeActive`:

```
-(void) checkInactiveLinks {
    AppDelegate *theDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    ...
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but reading my code I would think that on the second time the persistentStoreCoordinator getter is called it should return __persistentStoreCoordinator and not allocate and init a new one...

**UPDATE 2**
On the same exact line at the if statement I get this from time to time too:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary _hasPrecomputedKeyOrder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7dd3770
```

**UPDATE 3**

I edited my build scheme and turned on zombies and log exceptions under the diagnostics tab. Now I see `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator unlock]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8916090`. Note that I don't have any explicit locks in my code.

Comment: Are you editing the model without recreating a new version of the model first, by any chance?

Comment: @JPHribovsek if he's getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS would he have a log?

Comment: I am using GCD to use threading. But like I have been reading, I create a new ManagedObjectContext for each thread. Like this:     AppDelegate *theDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you are getting into that piece of code from multiple threads at the same time.  When you do lazy instantiation, you must make sure the "first time" through only one thread of execution will pass at the same time.  You can use the following strategy to synchronize access to it on the main thread.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Add this block of code.  Basically, it forces all threads that reach this
    // code to be processed in an ordered manner on the main thread.  The first
    // one will initialize the data, and the rest will just return with that
    // data.  However, it ensures the creation is not attempted multiple times.
    if (![NSThread currentThread].isMainThread) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            (void)[self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        });
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: One line can be simplified a wee bit: `if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {`

Comment: One more reason to be very careful with lazy instantiation.  I find I do lazy instantiation as premature optimization - time to rethink that.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using GCD to use threading.

And:

> From time to time my app crashes before it is fully loaded right at
>   the following line:

Sounds like the classic symptoms of a concurrency related bug;  intermittent and seemingly in the wrong spot.

CoreData has very [specific concurrency requirements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1).   Are you meeting them?

Comment: Yes I read that exact webpage when I started with CoreData and now a few hours ago again and I do meet their requirements. Mainly making sure you use a new MOC in each thread and you can share persistentStoreCoordinators.

Comment: OK -- just checking.  Concurrency is tricky stuff.   May still be a concurrency issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer spin lock, it's more clear approach than calling getter method recursively in the main thread.
Here is my solution:

```
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

@implementation MyClass {
    OSSpinLock _lock;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _lock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT;
    }
}


 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Lock the current thread
    OSSpinLockLock(&_lock);

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 

    // Unlock
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&_lock);

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using this method?

Comment: @Politta Personally for me is more clear, the code above ensures that, everything between `OSSpinLockLock(&_lock);` and `OSSpinLockUnlock(&_lock);` will be accessed only by one thread . If another thread tries to access it, have to wait the first one to complete execution (to reach `OSSpinLockUnlock(&_lock);`).                                           Here is some `OSSpinLockLock` documentation https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/OSSpinLockLock.3.html I hope that I was useful. Cheers 

Answer (score 0):

I think when you add a new persistent store you should first lock the persistent store coordinator so it does not interfere with other persistent stores.

In the code below `psc` is a separate reference to the newly created persistent store coordinator. If I understand your purpose correctly, this part of the method should perhaps be `dispatch_async`ed.

```
[psc lock];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator 
   addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                configuration:nil 
                          URL:storeURL 
                       options:nil error:&error]) {
   // deal with the error
}
[psc unlock];
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want a new psc... That's the hole point, I want new MOC's in my threads but share the PSC, because that is easy and it is the recommended way by Apple.

Comment: It is not a new psc, just a reference to the existing psc. This code is indeed from Apple (where to demonstrate iCloud also a persistent store has to be added asynchronously to a psc).

Comment: I gave it a try but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.